# Mocking a static method using powermockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I am testing some legacy code and would like to mock any calls to a static logger method: `LoggerFact.getLogger(Class class, String MethodName)`, here is what I tried:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({LoggerFact.class, MyClass.class, Logger.class})
public class MyClassTest
{
    @Before
    public void prepare() throws Exception
    {
      Logger mockedLogger = Mockito.mock(Logger.class);
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(LoggerFact.class);
      PowerMockito.when(LoggerFact.getLogger(MyClass.class, "test"))
                  .thenReturn(mockedLogger);
    }

    //My tests
}
```

The class that I am testing:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public String methodToBeTested()
    {
      Logger logger = LoggerFact.getLogger(this.getClass(), "test");
      logger.info("This is a test");
      //some logic
      return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

But I am recieving this error when I do this from the prepare when():

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
```

Did I miss something? I checked a lot of older posts about this issue, but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists_java/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64607243). Tested with JDK 8 and JDK 11.

The following works for me. (I have found that the order of initialization can be crucial):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(LoggerFact.class)
public class MyClassTestCase {
    private MyClass myClass = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LoggerFact.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodToBeTested() {
        Logger mockLogger = Mockito.mock(Logger.class);

        PowerMockito.when(LoggerFact.getLogger(eq(MyClass.class),eq("test"))).thenReturn(mockLogger);
        myClass = new MyClass();

        // test
        myClass.methodToBeTested();

        verify(mockLogger, times(1)).info(eq("This is a test"));
    }
}
```

As requested, from `build.gradle` in the example link above, here are the versions of libraries:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.6.0'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.7'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.7'
}
```

Comment: I've added the jar versions that are used in the online example. I'd suggest downloading that example and seeing if it works for you, just as a sanity-check.